# Big grid with minimum of 1000000 divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, performance

My idea is to create a big number of divs using php or js. (I write js since yesterday.)

So my self given task is to generate a grid of divs using php or js or both.
The idea so far is to have one general div as row and small cells inside. First I determine using php variable how long the row must be and after that I define the number of rows [easy so far]. My problem comes when I generate my grid. Using only php is VERY slow so I decided to use js as well. My first try resulted in cutting the time in half but still slow. So I asked myself is there a way to divide the work of js? Well yes... using functions of course! So I made a function called sector and tried to call it. It worked but still too slow. So what are the best practices for doing such a thing?

```
    <?php
$rowWidth = 200;                                  // width in pixels
$rowHeight = 100;                                 // height in pixels
$boxWidth = 1;                                  // box width in pixels
$boxHeight = 1;                                 // box height in pixels
?>
<body>
    <script>
    function sector(sector) {
        for (var i = 0*sector; i < (<?php echo $rowHeight / 100 ?> + 100*sector); i++) { // trying to manage sectors
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            // set style
            div.style.width = '<?php echo $rowWidth ?>';
            div.style.height = '<?php echo $boxHeight ?>';
            div.style.background = 'red';
            div.setAttribute('class', 'row'); // and make a class for future css (for now using inline css set by js)
            div.setAttribute('id', 'row'+i); // and make an id selector
            document.body.appendChild(div);
            for (var e = 0; e < <?php echo $rowWidth ?>; e++) {
                var box = document.createElement('div');
                // set style
                box.style.width = '<?php echo $boxWidth ?>';
                box.style.height = '<?php echo $boxHeight ?>';
                box.style.float = 'left';
                box.style.background = 'pink';
                box.setAttribute('class', 'box'); // and make a class for future css (for now using inline css set by js)
                box.setAttribute('id', 'box'+e); // and make an id selector
                document.getElementById('row'+i).appendChild(box); // joining my row
            }
        }
    }
    <?php for ($sector=0; $sector < ($rowWidth / 100) ; $sector++) { ?>
        //calling all sectors, calling all sectors... please report
        sector(<?php echo $sector+1 ?>);
    <?php } ?>
    </script>
</body>
```

**UPDATE:**
This looks similar to my idea.

http://www.businessinsider.com/reddit-place-april-fools-experiment-creates-pixel-art-final-version-2017-4

How did they make it?

Comment: did you try putting a timer on it to see where it's slowing down?  In my case it's the displaying of the whole darn thing.  So I put it into a bootgrid to make it faster

Comment: a) **why** are you trying to display a million divs b) what's PHP got to do with this and c) what makes you think there's a way to display a million divs without a performance hit?

Comment: You can't simply output a million div to the user's browser, it will be slow af... maybe divide them into pages if it is possible otherwise I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @Forbs The for cycle is slowing down....

Comment: @j08691 I want to create an image of sort and the php (using db) will hold the colors of every pixel and I thought the divs are the way to go. (be nice pls, I am still learning and that's why I'm asking for the best practice)

Comment: @MehdiBounya I want to make an image out of them - I am not sure if it has to be divs. I'm fine with a symbol too if it's easier for the browser.

Comment: Best practice is not doing any of that. Step 1 is not using a million divs, because that will kill the browser. Look into using an HTML5 canvas element. Step 2 is not storing individual pixels in a database, because that will kill your database. Look into actual image formats. Step 3 is just use a PNG or JPG or GIF ...

Comment: @Sammitch I found something that looks similar to my idea (maybe the same)

http://www.businessinsider.com/reddit-place-april-fools-experiment-creates-pixel-art-final-version-2017-4

How did they make the "drawing board" and how do they fill it?

Comment: As others has said, there is no way to optimise displaying 1 million divs as browsers are not designed to render 1 millions divs. Unless you go and create your own browser+rendering engine specifically for this purpose then this will be slow no matter what. The sheer size of your webpage alone will be rediculous, >10mb simply for the page DOM. In the example you posted, they used a canvas element, and drew to the canvas.

Comment: As for the reason why rendering 1 million pixels to a canvas is faster than rendering 1 million divs, a single pixel is *significantly* smaller than a DOMElement in terms of resource usage, several orders of magnitude smaller. A pixel is might simply be a single 32 bit value, meanwhile a HTMLElement contains many, many values. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement <- Simply look at the number of properties that a HTMLElement contains, and that's just the javascript interface. There could be many, many more values associated with it under the hood.It is not a simple type.

Comment: @NFSpeedy https://redditblog.com/2017/04/13/how-we-built-rplace/ TL;DR: an engineering team with massive amounts of experience, HTML5 canvas, reducing each pixel to 4 bits then storing it as a 4MB binary string in a very beefy database with assloads of caching and other fancy logic.

Comment: Why not generate the image serverside using gdi APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your purpose is to display an image where you will set the individual pixels, then you will get better results with a canvas element.

Here is a little demo:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function draw() {
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}

function setPixel(x, y, red, green, blue) {
    var offset = (y * canvas.width + x) * 4;
    imgData.data[offset] = red;
    imgData.data[offset+1] = green;
    imgData.data[offset+2] = blue;
    imgData.data[offset+3] = 255; // opacity
}

// Example: set some green pixels along a line
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    setPixel (i, i >> 2, 0, 128, 0);
}
draw(); // display the result.
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="180"></canvas>
```

Your PHP script should set the width and height attributes of the canvas element (HTML), and provide the coordinates and corresponding color codes to pass to `setPixel()`. Obviously it will important to let PHP provide that information in a concise format to minimise traffic.

If your database could store bitmap format, then you could just load that with an `<img src="...">` element and be done. The next best would be that your database stores the data as vectors, and you would only have to draw some lines and rectangles, which is less resource-requiring than having to pass & plot each pixel.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since such high numbers of HTMLElements all have their own properties and functions, slowing down the DOM beyond measurement.

Comment: What do you recommend for storing the pixels? Char and write each line of pixels and then explode() or? And if I am a user how do I choose what pixel do I want to color? Can I click the needed pixel or?

Comment: You could use a string for transmission, for example by compressing coordinate numbers into fixed length 36-base representation (PHP encode with `base_convert`, prepad with "0" to fixed length, JS decode with `substr` and `parseInt`). JavaScript can indeed give you the coordinates of a mouse click. Research it and if you have a specific problem, ask a new question about it.